# ggplot geom_line - setting colour of lines doesn't work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot several lines and then colouring them grey. However, whatever the colour I set, I get black lines. And if I put colour inside the aesthetic, then I get different colours (as expected), even if I specify the argument colour again outside aes().

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot)

country <- c(rep("A", 10), rep("B",10), rep("C", 10))
year <- c(2000:2009, 2000:2009, 2000:2009)
value <- c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, mean = 0.5), rnorm(10, mean = 1.1))

myData <- tibble(country, year, value) %>%
mutate(avg = mean(value))
ggplot(myData, 
       aes(x = year, y = value, country = country), 
       colour = "grey") +
geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = year, y = value, country = country, colour = I("grey"))) +
geom_line()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks ! works perfectly ! I was trying something with `scale_colour_manual(values = c(rep("grey", count(distinct(myData, country))))`, which works but isn't as understandable as this solution.
Although, can you quickly explain the I() function ? I find the help a bit confusing. Thanks !

Comment: Use I(...) if the color is specified explicitly; otherwise, the value is ignored and it will assign a color itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an othe approach: How you can use `scale_color_manual`:

```
p <- ggplot(myData, aes(x = year, y = value, color=country)) +
  geom_line() 

p + scale_color_manual(values=c("#a6a6a6", "#a6a6a6", "#a6a6a6"))
```

Instead of using hex color you could also use:
`p + scale_color_manual(values=c("gray69", "gray69", "gray69"))`

[image]

Comment: @TaeJae thanks, that works when you have a few countries. It gets complicated when you have more than 5 (and in my case, about 30).

Comment: This is no problem, Just use `p + scale_color_manual(values=rep("#a6a6a6", 50))`